# Восстановление процесса приложения при его повторном запуске

Tags: java, android, процесс

При нажатии на кнопку "Home", приложение сворачивается. Если открыть его через системный монитор, то приложение разворачивается в том же месте, где и была активность пользователя. Если открыть через иконку (повторные запуск), то приложение открывается на стартовом Activity.

Как восстановить (развернуть) процесс приложения при повторном его запуске?

Comment: Покажите код, хотя бы первой активити. Такого поведения не должно быть, запуск через иконку так же должен открывать активити, на которой была нажата "Home"

Comment: я бы сказал, покажите ваш манифест

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tP9KCAS4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю зачем вы дописали в манифесте каждому активити

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Но что бы сделать так как вам надо, вам просто нужно удалить эти строки. Проблема может быть только если у вас на этом завязан функционал.

Comment: именно это я и подозревал

Comment: @metalurgus, по факту, это самый частый прокол в таких случаях. ставят флаги, а сами даже не знают, что они делают.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, просто я не ожидал подобного эффекта. =(